# Turning RGB image to grayscale causes white to shine

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have tried to turn a RGB image into grayscale by manipulating the pixels:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("image.jpg")
pixels = img.load()

for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        avg = int(pixels[i,j][0] + pixels[i,j][1] + pixels[i,j][2] / 3)
        pixels[i,j] = (avg,avg,avg)

img.show()
```

It is gray for the most part, but the white parts of the image become a lot more noticeable. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a bracket.
Try this line:

```
avg = int((pixels[i,j][0] + pixels[i,j][1] + pixels[i,j][2]) / 3)
```

Comment: yepp - only last value was divided by 3

Answer (score 2):

Try a weighted average instead:

```
ave = int(0.30 * pixels[i,j][0] + 0.59 * pixels[i,j][1] + 0.11 * pixels[i,j][2])
```

According to [this article](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Color2BW/), those weights are supposed to "account for the eye's sensitivity to different colors."

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parentesis, but the image object actually has a function for converting to black and white. Try this:

```
img = Image.open("image.jpg").convert("L")
```

you can find the full documentation for it [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)